# Why is the constructor of the class called four times, and the destructor is only called twice when the program is about to end？

Tags: c++, class, constructor, destructor

Why is the constructor of the class called four times, and the destructor is only called twice when the program is about to end？

I want to construct a one-way circular linked list and it's OK, but I got some problems on the destructor of the `Buffer`class.

The code is as follows:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

class Buffer
{
public:
    Buffer(): Next(nullptr)
    {
        int id = ID + 1;
        ID++;
        std::cout << "Thi is the " << id << "th buffer." << endl;
    }
    ~Buffer()
    {
        cout << "The buffer is destructed." << endl;
    }

    shared_ptr<Buffer> Next;
    static int ID;
};

int Buffer::ID = 0;

int main()
{
    int LogBufferNum = 4;
    shared_ptr<Buffer> Head = std::make_shared<Buffer>();
    Head->Next = Head;
    LogBufferNum--;

    while (LogBufferNum > 0)
    {
        std::shared_ptr<Buffer> New = std::make_shared<Buffer>();
        std::shared_ptr<Buffer> Temp(Head);

        New->Next = Head;
        Temp->Next = New;
        Temp = New;

        LogBufferNum--;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

it prints as:

```
The is the 1th buffer.
The is the 2th buffer.
The is the 3th buffer.
The buffer is destructed.
The is the 4th buffer.
The buffer is destructed.
```

Any solutions? **Thank you very much**

Comment: To get a better picture of what is going on, it seems like `cout << "The buffer is destructed." << endl;` should instead be `cout << "The " << id << "th buffer is destructed." << endl;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a circular reference with `shared_ptr`, i.e. A contains a pointer to B and B contains a pointer to A, those object will never be destroyed. In this case two of your `Buffers` are pointing to each other. Try working out on paper what you are doing when you set up those pointers and you will see the circular reference.